# Name followed by "::" must be a class or namespace name error

Tags: visual-studio-2013, cuda, thrust

I was trying to compile the example test from [voxelpipe's code](https://code.google.com/p/voxelpipe/) but the compilation keeps failing with the following error

```
name followed by "::" must be a class or namespace name
```

and it points out to be in the following files `coarse.h`, `fine.h` and `abuffer.h`
I didn't change any part of the code so I was expecting it to compile fine after setting the include paths correctly (which they are). I leave here the piece of code where the errors are detected maybe someone can give me some advice on what I may be missing.

**coarse.h**

```
...
const int32 block_count = thrust::detail::device::cuda::arch::max_active_blocks(setup_kernel<BLOCK_SIZE, log_TILE_SIZE>, BLOCK_SIZE, 0);
...
const int32 block_count = thrust::detail::device::cuda::arch::max_active_blocks(coarse_raster_kernel<BLOCK_SIZE,log_TILE_SIZE,tile_id_type>, BLOCK_SIZE, 0);
...
dim3 dim_grid  = dim3( thrust::detail::device::cuda::arch::max_active_blocks(compute_tile_ranges<BLOCK_SIZE,tile_id_type>, BLOCK_SIZE, 0), 1, 1 );
```

**fine.h**

```
dim3 dim_grid  = dim3( thrust::detail::device::cuda::arch::max_active_blocks(FR::fine_raster_kernel<shader_type,BLOCK_SIZE,LOG_TILE_SIZE,VoxelType,VoxelizationType,BlendingMode>, BLOCK_SIZE, 0), 1, 1 );
```

**abuffer.h**

```
dim3 dim_grid  = dim3( thrust::detail::device::cuda::arch::max_active_blocks(AB::A_buffer_unsorted_small_kernel<shader_type,BLOCK_SIZE,VoxelType,VoxelizationType>, BLOCK_SIZE, 0), 1, 1 );
...
dim3 dim_grid  = dim3( thrust::detail::device::cuda::arch::max_active_blocks(AB::A_buffer_unsorted_large_kernel<shader_type,BLOCK_SIZE,VoxelType,VoxelizationType>, BLOCK_SIZE, 0), 1, 1 );
```

My best guess so far is that it is `thrust` causing the problem, but since I created a CUDA project in Visual Studio I think thrust should be recognized right away, shouldn't it?

Since all the code is written in `.h` files, there shouldn't be any problem of nvcc sending the file to c++ compiler, am I right?

Comment: The project uses elements of thrust that a typical program would not use (`thrust::detail::...`).  Such implementation details are liable to change from one thrust version to the next.  Since its a research project, that factor was probably not terribly important.  Your best bet is probably to compile with the exact version of thrust that was being used when that project was originally created/built.  If its not evident from the project, you may be able to make a guess based on the various file checkin dates.

Comment: What version thrust are you using? I guess that the internal functions used in that project don't exist anymore in the version of thrust you are using. In general, no-one should ever write code which relies on anything in the thrust::detail namespace because those are implementation details which can and do change from version to version.

Comment: I'm using the version that comes with CUDA 6.5, i'm not sure which one it is. My best bet is to compile with the same exact thrust version they used?

Comment: The [file checkin dates](https://code.google.com/p/voxelpipe/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc%2Fvoxelpipe) all appear to be October, 2011.  The [latest extant version of CUDA at that time](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive) seems to be CUDA 4.0.  The simplest approach might be to establish a clean system with the necessary infrastructure (e.g. OS and VS version compatible with CUDA 4.0) and try installing CUDA 4.0 (which will include thrust) and try building in that regime.  FYI CUDA 4.0 shipped with thrust 1.4

Comment: I will set the environment like that and see if that works, If so, I think I will need to dig a little deep into voxelpipe to adjust the code correctly. Thanks

Comment: The [project readme](https://code.google.com/p/voxelpipe/source/browse/trunk/README.txt) in fact suggests CUDA 4.0.  Other dependencies and system requirements are listed there as well which may be of interest.

Comment: Yes already have the external dependencies. I saw that of "CUDA 4.0 or later" so I thought it could work flawlessly with CUDA 6.5 but I believe some stuff changed. I'll check it and come back if I have some kind of solution.